# I am unable to identify the correct Xpath with chrome-webdriver using python to automate login process

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

While trying to give user name and password to the url "https://connect.garmin.com/signin/" using xpath in chrome webdriver in python, I'm getting the error "no such element: unable to locate element".

Xpath i used is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']").send_keys("usernameusername")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wait for the element to become clickable:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='username']")).send_keys('usernameusername')
```

Also, use single quotes around 'username'.

Comment: i am using python for scripting in Chrome web driver and ,i have given 30 sec wait time before this code but still same error